# EF: how to tackle many-to-many relation (some filtering involved)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, many-to-many, linq

I am a beginner in EF and LINQ and I would like to retrieve a list of categories (with filter) by product id.

So, I have many-to-many relation between `Product * <---> * Category` and I use the following code:

```
var categList = dbContext.Products
                 .Where(prod => prod.PROD_UID == 1234)
                 .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories)
                 .Distinct();

categList = SearchCategories(filter, categList);
categList = SortCategories(filter, categList);
categList = PageCategories(filter, categList);
```

where `SearchCategories` is used to reuse some code and looks like below

```
IQueryable<Category> SearchCategories(MyFilter filter, IQueryable<Category> source = null)
{
    source = source ?? this.dbContext.Categories;

    return source.Where(cat => [...filtering...] );
}
```

Although this looks ok, I would like to have it slightly optimized, with filtering inside the `SelectMany` (make use of `SearchCategories` inside `SelectMany`)... but I cannot make it work. I tried this, but gives me error

```
var categList = dbContext.Products
                 .Where(prod => prod.PROD_UID == 1234)
                 .SelectMany(cat => SearchCategories(filter, prod.Categories.AsQueryable()).AsEnumerable());

// throws LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'SearchCategories'
```

How could I filter the categories inside `SelectMany`?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code you cant have .SelectMany(cat => prod.Categories) you should have .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are confusing the server query with the client query there is no magic here.

your first query until Distinct is serialized and sent to the server, then the server sends a response and you then run a filter in your client.

when you put the `SearchCategories` in the server query it cant be resolver so you get the error.

you have two options here:

1:Just write all your query from `SearchCategories` in the first query making it run in the server

```
 .SelectMany(prod => prod.Categories.Where(c => [...filtering...]))
```

remember the filtering cant call client code.

2:You put a ToList or ToArray and then use the `SearchCategories` but this option wont optimize anything.

Comment: To get this right... My idea of creating that 'SearchCategories' function was to reuse the filtering code. In general, shall I forget about this when creating lambda expressions?

Comment: Probably I have to find a way how to build an 'Expression' to reuse code here, yet I am such a beginner on this